# why parameter.getType().isInstance(HttpServletRequest.class) return is false,but use "==" is true

Tags: java, instanceof

```
Parameter[] ps = method.getParameters();

Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for(int ij = 0;ij<ps.length;ij++){

    Parameter p = ps[ij];

    RequestParam rp = p.getAnnotation(RequestParam.class);

    if(rp != null){

        //do something

    }else {
        System.out.println(p.getType());
        System.out.println(p.getType().isInstance(HttpServletRequest.class));
        System.out.println(p.getType() == HttpServletRequest.class);
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
false
true
```

why use the "isInstance" is false and use "==" is true?
because the "instance of" can't judge implements relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

isInstance is equal to instanceOf

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof
>   operator.

The method return false because you are comparing a class (returned by p.getType()) to another class HttpServletRequest.class instead this method want an instance for example:

```
Dog bobby = new BobbyDog(); // class BobbyDog extends Dog
System.out.println(Dog.class.isInstance(bobby)); // correct use (return true)
System.out.println(Dog.class.isInstance(BobbyDog.class)); // incorrect use (return false)
```

The equals operator return true because the two class are equal

```
p.getType() == HttpServletRequest.class // true
HttpServletRequest.class == HttpServletRequest.class // true
```

if you want judge implements relationship you must use the method

```
isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)
```

> Determines if the class
>   or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as,
>   or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface
>   represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so;
>   otherwise it returns false. If this Class object represents a
>   primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class
>   parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.

Answer (score 7):

The type isn't an instance of the `HttpServletRequest` class, it's an instance of [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that contains the information about the `HttpServletRequest` class.